# Using Spring-Boot with Native Buildpack behind Corp. Proxy

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, proxy, buildpack

I am having an issue where the buildpack I am using as part of a native build with Spring Boot cannot download the required JDK to build the container image. It is not aware of my proxy settings for my corporate proxy.

Getting errors that cant download the JDK as cant locate the host - classic proxy issue.

What is the best way to set the proxy settings for a buildpack to use when using these packs as part of the Spring Boot native plugin (in my case Gradle).

I have tried:

- Setting proxy in my gradle.properties
- Setting proxy in my gradle-wreapper.properties
- Setting proxy within the IDE I am running gradle in
- Setting HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY env properties in Windows.

Thanks

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, managed to solve this one finally.

So the key was the `HTTP_PROXY` and `HTTPS_PROXY` setting, but had to put it in the correct place.

For me that was in the `environment` portion of the `bootBuildImage` gradle DSL.

```java
/**
 * Configure (Ahead-Of-Time) AOT Task.
 */
springAot {
    mode = AotMode.NATIVE       // NATIVE is default
    debugVerify = false         // false is default
    removeXmlSupport = false    // true is default
    removeSpelSupport = true    // false is default
    removeYamlSupport = true    // false is default
    removeJmxSupport = true     // true is default
    verify = true               // true is default
}

/**
 * Native Image Configuration.
 */
bootBuildImage {
    builder = 'paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny'
    environment = [
            'BP_NATIVE_IMAGE': 'true',
            'HTTP_PROXY' : 'http://www-myproxy.org:43924',
            'HTTPS_PROXY' : 'http://www-myproxy.org:43924'
    ]
}
```

That did the trick. The buildpack was able to detect the environment property correctly then and route the request to download items via the proxy properly.

Comment: 100%! If you're alternatively using `pack` cli, this happens automatically if those env variables are set locally, or if they are not set you can set them with `pack build -e HTTP_PROXY val -e HTTPS_PROXY val ...`.  See https://paketo.io/docs/howto/configuration/#proxy-configuration